# How to check if sqlite3 is compiled with HAVE_USLEEP

Tags: c, linux, sqlite

I would like to verify if my sqlite3 binary is compiled with `HAVE_USLEEP` option.

The compilation option is referred [here](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#usleep) and [here](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/howtocompile.html).

I wanted to check it with `PRAGMA compile_options;` but It does not return `HAVE_USLEEP` on any of my compilation attempts.

To compile the sqlite I run:

```sh
export CFLAGS="-DHAVE_USLEEP"
./configure
make
```

which gives me a lot of output ending with libtool report which appears to include the `-DHAVE_USLEEP`

`libtool: link: gcc -DHAVE_USLEEP -DSQLITE_OS_UNIX=1 ....`

`configure` also reports `usleep` present.

However the session with the compiled binary is as follows:

```
user@pc:~/Downloads/sqlite$ ./sqlite3 
SQLite version 3.31.0 2020-01-07 09:06:43
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> PRAGMA compile_options;
COMPILER=gcc-4.8.4
ENABLE_DBSTAT_VTAB
ENABLE_FTS4
ENABLE_JSON1
ENABLE_RTREE
ENABLE_STMTVTAB
ENABLE_UNKNOWN_SQL_FUNCTION
HAVE_ISNAN
THREADSAFE=1
sqlite>
```

I've tried both `-DHAVE_USLEEP` and `-DHAVE_USLEEP=1`.

At this point I don't know how to approach this - the `DHAVE_USLEEP` appears to be passed to the `libtool` but the option is missing from the report. I've either compiled it without the option (somehow), or the `PRAGMA compiled_options` does not return the `DHAVE_USLEEP`. I'm looking for a way to differentiate the states to be able to debug it further.

Thanks for any idea regarding this.

Comment: I shall add that it's weird that my system version shows flags like HAVE_ISNAN but I cannot get a manually built sqlite3 to output `HAVE_ISNAN` with `PRAGMA compile_options;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just see if the symbol exists in the sqlite library:

```
$ nm /path/to/your/libsqlite3.a | grep usleep
             U usleep
```

Comment: Just to complete this answer for others, the basic make (for sqlite3) does not produce the `libsqlite3.a` file, I've successfully created it with following `ar rcs libsqlite3.a sqlite3.o`, then @Shawn's answer works.

Comment: @MarekSchwarz Makes it for me. Though I build from the full source, not the distributed amalgamation because of some of the options I use. But replace `.a` with `.so`, or use the `sqlite3` executable instead of the library. Shouldn't make a difference. (The configure script defaults to enabling both static and shared libraries...)

Answer (score 0):

here's how

1. install GDB (a linux debugger) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/installing_gdb.htm
2. run `python3` REPL and leave it open

in another terminal,

1. get the PID of the running REPL:
   `ps aux | grep python3`
2. in another terminal, attach GDB to the running python REPL (make sure you're root)
   `sudo gdb -p <PID>`
3. try
   `disass __sleep`.
   if you can't find the __sleep function, try this gdb command
   `info functions`
   and try to find a function with "sleep" in it then `disass <function_name_you_found>`
4. look for a call to **__GI___nanosleep**, if you find it, then USLEEP is enabled.